# Remove duplicates and original from list

Tags: python, list, duplicates

Given a list of strings I want to remove the duplicates and original word.

For example:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e']
```

The output should have the duplicates removed,
so something like this `['a', 'b', 'd']`

I do not need to preserve the order.

Answer (score 6):

Use a [`collections.Counter()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), then keep only those values with a count of 1:

```
from collections import counter

[k for k, v in Counter(lst).items() if v == 1]
```

This is a O(N) algorithm; you just need to loop through the list of N items once, then a second loop over fewer items (< N) to extract those values that appear just once.

If order is important and you are using Python < 3.6, separate the steps:

```
counts = Counter(lst)
[k for k in lst if counts[k] == 1]
```

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e']
>>> [k for k, v in Counter(lst).items() if v == 1]
['a', 'b', 'd']
>>> counts = Counter(lst)
>>> [k for k in lst if counts[k] == 1]
['a', 'b', 'd']
```

That the order is the same for both approaches is a coincidence; for Python versions before Python 3.6, other inputs may result in a different order.

In Python 3.6 the implementation for dictionaries changed and input order is now retained.

Answer (score 4):

```
t = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e']
print [a for a in t if t.count(a) == 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e']
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(lst)
print([k for k,v in c.items() if v == 1 ])
```

[collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) will count the occurrences of each element, we keep the elements whose `count/value is == 1` with `if v == 1`

Answer (score 2):

**@Padraic:**

If your list is:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e']
```

then

```
list(set(lst))
```

would return the following:

```
['a', 'c', 'b', 'e', 'd']
```

which is not the thing adhankar wants..

**Filtering all duplicates completely** can be easily done with a list comprehension:

```
[item for item in lst if lst.count(item) == 1]
```

The output of this would be:

```
['a', 'b', 'd']
```

*item* stands for every item in the list *lst*, but it is only appended to the new list if *lst.count(item)* equals 1, which ensures, that the item only exists once in the original list *lst*.

Look up List Comprehension for more information: [Python list comprehension documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: your algorithm is quadratic

Comment: really? python list comprehensions with an if have quadratic time complexity? could you explain this? what's the time complexity of your algorithm?

Comment: what do you think lst.count(item) is doing?

Comment: whats the complexity of your solution?

Comment: it is an `O(n)` algorithm

Answer (score -1):

You could make a secondary empty list and only append items that aren't already in it.

```
oldList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e']
newList = []
for item in oldList:
    if item not in newList:
        newList.append(item)
print newList
```

I don't have an interpreter with me, but the logic seems sound.

Comment: This also gives me ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], i need the output to be ['a', 'b', 'd']