# Delete both repeated elements from a list of lists in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have the list

Input:
`L = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]`

Output:
`L=  [[5, 6, 7], [ 2, 3, 5]]`

I want to check if `L[i]== L[j]`, then I will remove `L[j]` from the list .

Can you help me?

This is my code:

```
for i in range(0,len(L) - 1):
    for j in range(1,len(L) - 1):
        if (L[i] == L[j]):
            L.remove(L[j])

print(L)
```

But it gives an error:

```
if (L[i] == L[j]):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: So you want to remove `L1` from the list, and add `L2` to the list? If so: `L.remove(L1); L.append(L2)`.

Comment: but you need to check if L1 is in the list and L2 is not in the list

Answer (score 3):

Once you remove an element of `L`, the shape of `L` changes. This is why you are getting the index out of range error: you are still iterating over the original length of `L`, but once you start removing elements from `L` it becomes shorter than that.

You can get around this by creating a new list with `count`:

```
L2 = [sublist for sublist in L if L.count(sublist) == 1]

print(L2)
>>> [[5, 6, 7], [2, 3, 5]]
```

---

<sup>**Note:** your current logic, even if it adapted to the changing length of `L`, would not return your desired output. It would still retain the first 'copy' of all duplicate elements, as [Richard Rublev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51745688/9067615) below produces.</sup>

---

If this is too slow (O(n<sup>2</sup>)), here is an O(n) solution using [`Counter`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790493/remove-duplicate-and-original-from-list-python):

```
from collections import Counter

# Converting elements to hashable type
L = [tuple(sublist) for sublist in L]
cnt = Counter(L)

# Grabbing non-duplicated items
L2 = [k for k, v in cnt.items() if v == 1]

# Converting elements back to lists
L2 = [list(sublist) for sublist in L2]

print(L2)   
>>> [[5, 6, 7], [2, 3, 5]]
```

Comment: but it too slow when I run a huge list,

Comment: @tdp have added an alternate solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
testdata = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
unique = [list(x) for x in set(tuple(x) for x in testdata)]
```

Result

```
[[2, 3, 5], [2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: A side effect of this is that it does not preserve order.

Comment: Though this follows the logic in OP's code: `I want to check if L[i]== L[j], then I will remove L[j] from the list`, judging by the title and `expected output` I suspect OP really wants **all** duplicate entries removed - not just the extra copies.

Comment: Yes,I made a mistake,I have seen now that he wants to remove duplicates.

Comment: but this is not the output I want, I think no [2,3,4] and [1,2,3] in the outuput