# Remove duplicate and original in list of dictionary ignoring specific keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to find duplicates in a list of dict ignoring specific keys and removing both the duplicate and original list. In the example when making the comparison I want to ignore keys `STATUS` and `Ferry LAST SPEED`.

```
list = [{'DEPARTURE PORT': 'Ischia', 'STATUS': 'Unavailable', 
         'COMPANY': 'Caremar', 'FERRY LAST SPEED': 0.0, 
         'DEPARTURE DATE': '2020-06-22'}, 
        {'DEPARTURE PORT': 'Ischia', 'STATUS': 'Active', 
         'COMPANY': 'Caremar', 'FERRY LAST SPEED': 1.0, 
         'DEPARTURE DATE': '2020-06-22'}]
```

Desired output:

```
list = []
```

My current code compares all keys in both entries and is unable to exclude `STATUS` and `SPEED`. How can I improve it so it behaves as wanted?

```py
from collections import Counter

def freeze(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        return frozenset((key, freeze(value)) for key, value in d.items())

    elif isinstance(d, list):
        return tuple(freeze(value) for value in d)
    return d
key = freeze(list)
list = ([k for k, v in Counter(key).items() if v == 1])
```

I've found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790493/remove-duplicate-and-original-from-list-python) but it includes all keys in determining duplicates.

Comment: So it's like [a, a, b, f, d, g, d, d] to [b, f, g]?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a global variable of keys to exclude:

```py
EXCLUDE_SET = set("STATUS", "SPEED")
```

Then, for your return statement, use:

```py
return frozenset((key, freeze(value)) for key, value in d.items() if key not in EXCLUDE_SET)
```